# Stop sound file when back pressed in Android

Tags: android, media-player, onbackpressed

I have some audio files in listview which I play them randomly. while the file is playing I want to go back by pressing the back button, so in method onBackpressed I put the following

```
 if(mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }else
    {
        //show a message or something
    }
```

but its not working and I get a FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN NullpointerException in the case the audio its not playing

Comment: so `mMediaPlayer` is null, check that is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code , it may help you

```
 if(mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
    {
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }else
    {
        //show a message or something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
super.onStop();  

if(mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
mMediaPlayer.stop();
mMediaPlayer.release();
mMediaPlayer = null;
}

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
 super.onDestroy();
if(mMediaPlayer!=null && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
 mMediaPlayer.stop();
 mMediaPlayer.release();
 mMediaPlayer = null;  
}
}
```